# Cannot get background URL Session to return

Tags: ios, background, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I have tried and failed many times to get some inherited code to successfully send a background session request. When in the foreground, it works flawlessly, but in the background it will either never return, or, in some cases, receive a auth challenge.

The code to create the request is pretty boilerplate:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig =
[NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:identifier];
sessionConfig.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true;
sessionConfig.discretionary = false;
sessionConfig.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60 * 60 * 24; //One day. Default is 7 days!

/* Create session, and optionally set a NSURLSessionDelegate. */
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig
                                                      delegate:self
                                                 delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [NSURLComponents new];
urlComponents.scheme           = @"https";
urlComponents.host             = @"jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
urlComponents.path             = @"/posts/1";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[urlComponents URL]];
request.HTTPMethod           = @"PUT";

NSLog(@"Making request: %@", request);

/* Start a new Task */
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request];
[task resume];
```

But I never get anything back. I do have the required background modes (probably)

```
      <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
      <array>
              <string>fetch</string>
              <string>remote-notification</string>
      </array>
```

and my delegate is delegating everything

```
<NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDataDelegate,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate,NSURLConnectionDelegate,NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>
```

Any help would be appreciated- I'm pretty sure I'm missing just one line of code somewhere.  I even went so far as to create a GitHub repo just to test this code out- it schedules a Local Notification to allow you to run the session task in the background.

[GitHub repo for BackgroundSender](https://github.com/nailbones/backgroundSender/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the app delegate's [`handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622941-application?language=objc), you are doing nothing with the completion handler. You should:

- save copy of the `completionHandler`;
- start the background `NSURLSession` with that identifier; and
- when done handling all of the delegate methods, call the saved completion handler; we often do that in [`URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsessiondelegate/1617185-urlsessiondidfinisheventsforback?language=objc).

---

By the way, you shouldn't use data tasks with background sessions. You generally should use a download or upload task.

---

Also, those background modes are not necessary for background `NSURLSession`. Background fetch is designed for a different problem, namely periodically polling to see if your server has data available. If you need that, then by all means, use the `fetch` background mode, but realize that this is a separate topic from merely performing background requests.

See [Fetching Small Amounts of Content Opportunistically](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW56) in the *App Programming Guide for iOS: Background Execution* for a discussion of background fetch, and compare that to the [Downloading Content in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5) section.

Likewise, the `remote-notification` key is unrelated, too. As the docs say, `remote-notification` is used when "The app wants to start downloading content when a push notification arrives. Use this notification to minimize the delay in showing content related to the push notification."

Comment: handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession didn't have an implementation as I have never seen it called.  Your comment about not using data tasks seemed to be the issue- I changed it to download task just to see if it would work, and immediately got a handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession call.  

The remote-notification key is an artifact from the original project, but thought it might also apply to starting tasks kicked off by local notifications.

Comment: Very good. BTW, do make sure to call that completion handler passed to `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession` when you're done processing the delegate methods for the completed requests or else the OS will kill your app, rather than gracefully suspending it, thereby preventing other background processes (like remote notifications and background fetch).